# Flutter: ColorScheme.secondary never applied to set accent color

Tags: flutter, themes, deprecation-warning, accent-color

My code - accent color set with deprecated `accentColor` property, it works, red color applied:

```
return VersionBanner(
      text: "DEV",
      visible: globals.isDev,
      location: BannerLocation.bottomEnd,
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'MyApp',
        theme: ThemeData(
          accentColor: Colors.red,
          appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
            elevation: 0,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            foregroundColor: Colors.black,
            systemOverlayStyle: overlayStyle,
          ),
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
          primaryColor: Colors.white,
          textTheme: AppTheme.textTheme,
          pageTransitionsTheme: PageTransitionsTheme(builders: {
            TargetPlatform.android: ZoomPageTransitionsBuilder(),
            TargetPlatform.iOS: CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilder()
          }),
        ),
        home: globals.isLogged ? HomePage() : LoginPage(),
        localizationsDelegates: [
          GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
          DefaultMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
          DefaultCupertinoLocalizations.delegate
        ],
        supportedLocales: [
          const Locale('pl', 'PL'),
        ],
        routes: routes,
      ),
    );
```

I migrated to `ColorScheme` call this way:

```
return VersionBanner(
      text: "DEV",
      visible: globals.isDev,
      location: BannerLocation.bottomEnd,
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'MyApp',
        theme: ThemeData(
          appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
            elevation: 0,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            foregroundColor: Colors.black,
            systemOverlayStyle: overlayStyle,
          ),
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
          primaryColor: Colors.white,
          textTheme: AppTheme.textTheme,
          pageTransitionsTheme: PageTransitionsTheme(builders: {
            TargetPlatform.android: ZoomPageTransitionsBuilder(),
            TargetPlatform.iOS: CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilder()
          }), colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch().copyWith(secondary: Colors.red),
        ),
        home: globals.isLogged ? HomePage() : LoginPage(),
        localizationsDelegates: [
          GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
          DefaultMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
          DefaultCupertinoLocalizations.delegate
        ],
        supportedLocales: [
          const Locale('pl', 'PL'),
        ],
        routes: routes,
      ),
    );
```

But accent color is never applied in this case, no mater what secondary color is set, accent color is always blue. So - deprecated approach works just fine, new approach does not.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you looking for color changes for `Radio` and `Checkbox` then it pick up the accent color from `toggleableActiveColor` theme property.

You need to use that property in the theme like this.

```
    theme: ThemeData(
     //...
      toggleableActiveColor : Colors.red
    //...
    home: ...,
    localizationsDelegates: [
      //...
    ],
    supportedLocales: [
      const Locale('pl', 'PL'),
    ],
    routes: routes,
  ),
```

For more properties changes check this [document](https://docs.google.com/document/u/0/d/1kzIOQN4QYfVsc5lMZgy_A-FWGXBAJBMySGqZqsJytcE/mobilebasic).